# Handling simultaneous requests in Apache 2 and php-fpm

Tags: php, php-fpm, apache2, timeout, debian-10

We have a Debian 10 server with Apache2 and PHP-FPM installed.

The problem is that when I try to process multiple requests simultaneously from one client, server doesn't handle it correctly.

For example, I send a request from **clientA** that may take 60 seconds to proceed, now I send 10 other requests from the same client which are easy to process and would response in less than 1 sec in a normal situation, but they wait until the first request (60sec one) completes and only then they start being processed and giving response. Sometimes, easy requests have been returning **error code 504 Timeout** because of the heavy process.

Note that while a heavy process from cliantA is being processed, other clients still can send requests, so it's a problem only with the client who is sending the heavy request.

I almost tried nothing because I didn't know what to search and the results I had, just wasn't correct for my problem.

For any other information or configurations you think I need to share, please comment below.

All your help is appreciated.

Comment: I Know this question may be a little confusing, but I appreciate anything that makes me a few steps closer to the answer! If you need more detailed info about this problem, just send a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Check the php-fpm slow log.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for your contribution, I know which process is running slowly and I can't change it as it is already in it's best performance that is currently possible. I just want the server to process other small requests as well even while a large process from the same client is being processed.

Comment: We cannot really help if you do not share any relevant information!

Comment: @MichaelHampton What information do you mean? What should I share? I just asked above that if anything is needed, tell me to update the question. Thanks